# Am I required to handle OpenId?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am developing with the quickbooks sdk v2 to integrate my application with quickbooks online. If I do not want my app in the intuit app store is it necessary to do anything with open id? My users will only be connecting to QB through the "Connect to quickbooks" button within my app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I do not want my app in the intuit app store is it necessary to do anything with open id?

If you don't want to be listed in AppCenter, you don't have to do anything at all with OpenID.

Comment: thanks! also just want to say your write ups are the only thing that got me through interfacing with qbXML a year ago or so. go consolibyte!

Comment: Thanks for the nice words! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Consolibyte is correct. Please refer:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0030_integrate_your_app